# Are there any client side report writers for Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, reportviewer

I am thinking of creating a Silverlight application that keeps on the data on the client.  Are there any report writers that will run within a Siverlight application.

(I wish to use Silverlight rather then WPF as it is more likely a customer will already have Siverlight installed, and it works on Macs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, try SharpShooter by Perpetuum.  The workflow involves sending data to the server for report generation, then it is sent back to the client in pdf, word, etc format for display.  I don't know if that's too server heavy for your needs but the process is quite fast for moderate amounts of data and you can't tell it's being round-tripped.  Hth.

http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/Report-Sharp-Shooter-for-Silverlight.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option that's soon to be released:
http://smartwebcontrols.com/